# Use uppercase letters adding new enum value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, alembic

I have an enum `datasetId`, to which I'd like to add another value.

However, this doesn't work:

```
ALTER TYPE datasetId ADD VALUE 'SOME_VALUE'
```

and fails with

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) type "datasetid" does not exist
```

I believe this is because of the uppercase letter in the enum name. How to I get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I believe this is because of the uppercase letter in the enum name." -- Enclose identifiers with special characters or where casing matters in double quotes:

```
ALTER TYPE "datasetId" ADD VALUE 'SOME_VALUE';
```

Or, the recommended way, just don't use identifiers with special characters or meaningful casing at all. At the end of the day they're just annoying.